# Can't set list of objects from viewmodel to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I set a list of objects coming from my viewmodel to a javascript variable to use in my js file? I'm getting an error when I try to set it.

Here is my viewmodel

```
public class TargetListAddressesViewModel
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the address object

```
 public partial class Address   
{
    [Column] public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [Column] public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    [Column] public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [Column] public int ParentTypeId { get; set; }
    [Column] public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Column] public string City { get; set; }
    [Column] public string State { get; set; }
    [Column] public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    [Column] public string Country { get; set; }
    [Column] public string AddressHash { get; set; }
    [Column] public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    [Column] public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    [Column] public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where I try and set it to a js variable, but it throws an error that says "VM320917:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal"

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var organizationId = @Html.Raw(Model.OrganizationId);
  var addresses = @Html.Raw(Model.Addresses);
</script>
```

Comment: `var addresses = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Addresses))`

Comment: And `var organizationId = @Model.OrganizationId;`

Answer (score 0):

var addresses = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Addresses))